# dicttoxml throws AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror, dicttoxml

I try to check how `dicttoxml` is working. But I receive this error from within the `dicttoxml` module.
I am starting program from geany.
Can anybody help?
Thanks!

```
import dicttoxml

myDict = {'myKey':"theirValue"};

xml =dicttoxml.dicttoxml(myDict);
```

Output is:

```
martin@saturn:~/it/python/python_work$ /bin/sh /tmp/geany_run_script_Q2NH3Z.sh
0.32000000000000006
1.6666666666666667
['1', '6666666666666667']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dicttoxmlExmp.py", line 4, in <module>
    xml =dicttoxml.dicttoxml(myDict);
  File "/home/martin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dicttoxml.py", line 393, in dicttoxml
    convert(obj, ids, attr_type, item_func, cdata, parent=custom_root), 
  File "/home/martin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dicttoxml.py", line 176, in convert
    if isinstance(obj, numbers.Number) or type(obj) in (str, unicode):
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'
```

Comment: I think you can simply run as `python yourscript`. It worked fine in my case.

Comment: Thank you for testing and the answer!

Comment: Sorry!!! I had a numbers.py file in the same directory, so dicttoxml took this one. Namespace issue... - How can I close this question or mark it as solved?

Comment: You can mark the answer if you think that solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

> python yourscript

Instead of running it as a shell script.